# How to check any value from Decimal array exist in a decimal field of a table?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Let's I have a decimal array `BOOK_NO[]`. I have existing query like this:

```
PrintOrderList = (
    from t1 in db.DIS_SET_PRINT_REQ
    join t2 in db.RND_BOOK on t1.F_BOOK_NO equals t2.BOOK_NO into first_joined
    where (t1.IS_EXIST == 1 && 
        t1.F_COMPANY_NO == Company_No &&  
        @book_no.(t1.F_BOOK_NO))
    from dept_data in first_joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new DIS_SET_PRINT_REQ_R_SINGLE_MODEL
    {
        BOOK_NO = dept_data.BOOK_NO,
        BOOK_NAME = dept_data.BOOK_NAME,
        EDITION_NAME = dept_data.RND_SET_BOOK_EDITION.BOOK_EDITION_NAME,
        FISCAL_YEAR = t1.SNS_SET_FISCAL_YEAR.FISCAL_YEAR_NAME,
        ACADEMIC_LEVEL = dept_data.RND_SET_BOOK_ACA_LEVEL.BOOK_ACA_LEVEL_NAME,
        PRINT_QUANTITY = t1.BOOK_QTY,
        PRINT_REQ_NO = t1.PRINT_REQ_NO,
        PRINT_SEQ = (db.DIS_SET_PRINT_REQ_DTL.Where(x => x.F_PRINT_REQ_NO == t1.PRINT_REQ_NO)
                                             .Where(x => x.IS_EXIST == 1)
                                             .OrderBy(x => x.PRINT_REQ_DTL_NO)),
        FISCAL_YEAR_NO = t1.F_FISCAL_YEAR_NO,
        EDITION_NO = t1.RND_BOOK.F_BOOK_EDITION_NO,
        ACADEMIC_LEVEL_NO = dept_data.RND_SET_BOOK_ACA_LEVEL.BOOK_ACA_LEVEL_NO,
        CATEGORY_NO = dept_data.F_BOOK_CATEGORY_NO
    }).ToList();
```

Here I need to put a condition that `BOOK_NO[]` contains any `t1.F_BOOK_NO`

Comment: Question is unclear. Do you want to make sure that each item `t1` exists in the `BOOK_NO[]`? Meaning that all the records in `PrintOrderList ` will be records that have a matching item in `BOOK_NO[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Contains` on the `BOOK_NO[]` to check that the `t1.BOOK_NO` is in it

```
PrintOrderList = (
    from t1 in db.DIS_SET_PRINT_REQ
    join t2 in db.RND_BOOK on t1.F_BOOK_NO equals t2.BOOK_NO into first_joined
    where t1.IS_EXIST == 1 && 
        t1.F_COMPANY_NO == Company_No &&  
        book_no.Contains(t1.F_BOOK_NO)
    from dept_data in first_joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new DIS_SET_PRINT_REQ_R_SINGLE_MODEL
    {
        BOOK_NO = dept_data.BOOK_NO,
        BOOK_NAME = dept_data.BOOK_NAME,
        EDITION_NAME = dept_data.RND_SET_BOOK_EDITION.BOOK_EDITION_NAME,
        FISCAL_YEAR = t1.SNS_SET_FISCAL_YEAR.FISCAL_YEAR_NAME,
        ACADEMIC_LEVEL = dept_data.RND_SET_BOOK_ACA_LEVEL.BOOK_ACA_LEVEL_NAME,
        PRINT_QUANTITY = t1.BOOK_QTY,
        PRINT_REQ_NO = t1.PRINT_REQ_NO,
        PRINT_SEQ = (db.DIS_SET_PRINT_REQ_DTL.Where(x => x.F_PRINT_REQ_NO == t1.PRINT_REQ_NO)
                                             .Where(x => x.IS_EXIST == 1)
                                             .OrderBy(x => x.PRINT_REQ_DTL_NO)),
        FISCAL_YEAR_NO = t1.F_FISCAL_YEAR_NO,
        EDITION_NO = t1.RND_BOOK.F_BOOK_EDITION_NO,
        ACADEMIC_LEVEL_NO = dept_data.RND_SET_BOOK_ACA_LEVEL.BOOK_ACA_LEVEL_NO,
        CATEGORY_NO = dept_data.F_BOOK_CATEGORY_NO
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: On thanks for your reply but `contains` only works for string matching.

Comment: No :) contains is an Extension Method of Enumerable and will work for any TSource that by the "default equality comparer" - So also for Decimal

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan - Did it help?

Comment: Yeah I did a little update of your code. It worked now. Thanks

Comment: I had to use this process because I had a casting inconsistency between 'BOOK_NO[]' and Model variable.

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan - I can't accept the edit because only in the edit you actually explain that `BOOK_NO[]` is not a `decimal[]`... - It will be wrong of me to accept it unless the question explains it first. and in the question you wrote _I have a decimal array_

Comment: Yes I have a decimal array as well as using (.contains) it wouldn't work out.